# Why cannot I open .y files when I can open .jpg file in opencv mat class

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to convert jpg file to .y file and show the converted .y file by using Mat class.
However, while I can read jpg file I cannot read .y file is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

void main()
{
    Mat image = imread("lena.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    unsigned char** Y;
    Y = (unsigned char**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*) * image.rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
        Y[i] = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * image.cols);

    FILE* fp;
    fopen_s(&fp, "lena.y", "wb");

    double sum = 0;
    int j;
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < image.cols * 3; j++)
        {
            
                if (j%3 == 0)
                {
                    if (j != 0)
                    {
                        Y[i][(j / 3) - 1] = static_cast<uchar>(sum);
                        sum = 0;
                    }
                    sum += 0.299 * image.at<uchar>(i, j);
                }
                    
                else if (j%3 == 1)
                    sum += 0.587 * image.at<uchar>(i, j);
                else if (j%3== 2)
                    sum += 0.114 * image.at<uchar>(i, j);
        }
        Y[i][(j / 3) - 1] = static_cast<uchar>(sum);
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<image.rows;i++)
        fwrite(Y[i], 1, image.cols, fp);

    fclose(fp);
    Mat new_image = imread("lena.y", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (new_image.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open image!\n";
        return;
    }

    imshow("gray", image);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).